# Don't record in realtime with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

So for my little application, I'm producing images and pipe them into FFmpeg.

But my application is not running real time. So producing a frame could take more than the actual FPS, but I want FFmpeg to count it only as a frame.

So if it takes for example 20 seconds to produce a single second of animation, I don't want to look like 20 seconds in the recorded video, but actually one second.

Is there a parameter for that? I couldn't find anything.

My current command line is:

`ffmpeg -s 1920x1080 -an -r 30 -pix_fmt rgb24 -f rawvideo -i pipe:0 test.mp4`

Comment: Share the full log.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, never saw such an option. Perhaps you can change your application: create the image files and if the amount is > X (100 for example), run ffmpeg with `-f image2pipe` (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow) and delete the images. Repeat until finished and concat the created videos.

Comment: @UweMannl that looks like the best solution. And when everything is done, concatenate the videos.